# WiiU error code at on-line play

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

[image: error code from MH3U]

I have gotten this error every time I try to play online quests.
I can access the world, the lobby, but when I choose a room I get this message.
The same happens with other games but the code is different.
Is there someone with the same problem?

Comment: I believe the 3U servers are retired; don't think they exist anymore.

Comment: Like Frank has mentioned, I believe Online Multiplayer for the WiiU has been shut down. Can you try playing a different game online, or just connect the internet via the console and see?

Comment: Ok, but If that were the case, Capcom would have disclosed the deactivation of the server.